# Combining multiple image files into one image using qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, gnuplot

I have divided my image in different parts (for some reason). I have done that using QT-creator in ubuntu. For image creation, I have used gnuplot in qt-creator.
 Now I want to print that image (in eps format). But I don't know how to combine these parts in one single file.

Any help in combining these parts would be highly appreciated.

regards,

Hammad Tariq

Comment: Do you need to combine images programmaticaly?

Comment: Sorry, but almost all information you provided are useless and the helpful parts are missing: Do you only want to combine your ready-made images? Which format do they have? Do you just need a utility for that, or do it in C++ or what?

Comment: @vahancho yes I need to combine them pragmatically in Qt using C++

Comment: @Christoph, no the images are not ready-made. I make them in qt-creator. But there are meant to be created in parts. And I have mentioned the format (.eps). And I want to combine them in Qt-creator using C++.

Comment: With due respect, it would be great if you guys could help rather than VOTING DOWN my question.
If you can't understand my statement/query, then ask for explanation. Thanks

Comment: That's what I did, but you should also invest more time to provide a good question by yourself, read http://whathaveyoutried.com/. So you have several eps images which you want to combine to one eps image? That means you are looking for a C++ library which can handle eps (or maybe pdf) images? Or for a command line utility which can do this? That has nothing to do with Qt, QtCreator or gnuplot, because in the end you have several eps image files which you want to combine. That my understanding of your question...

Comment: I got what you are saying, and I apologize for being vague in my statement. Actually I am new to these forums and learning my way to follow the rules.

And yes, I need to combine several eps files in one using C++ in Qt. I mentioned Qt to tell my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in C++, but in your case it is very convenient to use commandline utilities, since your images created with gnuplot are saved as files anyway.

The command line call is:

```
psjoin A.ps B.ps C.ps D.ps | psnup -4 > ABCD.ps
```

Maybe you need to tweak the size and positions of the images, see `man psnup`.

For this you need to save the images a `.ps`, not as `.eps`, i.e. use `set terminal postscript` instead of `set terminal postscript eps`. In your case that shouldn't change anything, but the above programs seem to work properly only with PS.

These programs are included in Ubuntu's [psutils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/psutils) package.